# These dependencies were not found: asyncToGenerator & 9 others

Tags: node.js, node-modules, tiptap

I've been trying to implement TipTap in one of my projects. I installed both tiptap & tiptap extensions:

```
"tiptap": "^1.29.4",
"tiptap-extensions": "^1.32.1",
```

I just used the example on the Github page, i.e. https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap#extensions

For some reason, that gives me the following errors:

[image]

Any idea how to solve this? Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: have you tried doing `npm install --save ...` as it suggests?

Comment: Yes, doesn't do anything